# How to disable caching in electron

Tags: node.js, caching, electron

I can disable caching in electron like

```
const { app } = require ("electron");
app.commandLine.appendSwitch ("disable-http-cache");
```

But this will disable cache in whole app. I dont want this behaviour. I want to disable caching for specific image elemment only but not all image elements

How can I disable cache for specific image in electron?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the stored cache per request if you add an extra header like [`Cache-Control: no-cache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#no-cache_2).